# TYPO3 6.2 no alternate language content

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I've created a multilingual TYPO3 6.2 website with fluid and Gridelements.
I have a big Problem with the language translations (btw: same problems occur in TYPO3 7.6)

If I create an alternative page language with **no** content inside, I want to show the **default language**, in my case German.
Otherwise, if there **is** some content on the translated (english) site, the german default should be hidden and the **complete alternativ language content** should be visible.

In my case it is **only** possible to translate exakt these parts from the german default language and it is not possible to create some new content which is not shown in the default language. In the TYPO3-backend I can create the new content, but it will not be shown.

If I set `config.sys_language_overlay = 0` at Typoscript, the new content is visible, but the complete default content isn't shown.

Which Settings are necessary to show the complete content at the alternative language and the default content for empty pages?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
styles.content.get.select.includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
styles.content.getLeft.select.includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
styles.content.getRight.select.includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
```

And here  my Typoscript

```
### language Menü ###
lib.langselect = COA
lib.langselect {    
  wrap = <ul class="langNav">|</li></ul></ul>   
  30 = HMENU
  30 {
    special = language
    special.value = 0,1,7
    special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      noBlur = 1
      # Standard Sprachen
      NO = 1
      NO {
        linkWrap = <li>|</li>
        stdWrap.override = Deutsch /|| English /
        doNotLinkIt = 1
        stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = page:uid
        stdWrap.typolink.additionalParams = &L=0 || &L=1
        stdWrap.typolink.addQueryString = 1
        stdWrap.typolink.addQueryString.exclude = L,id,cHash,no_cache
        stdWrap.typolink.addQueryString.method = GET
        stdWrap.typolink.useCacheHash = 1
        stdWrap.typolink.no_cache = 0
      }        
      ACT < .NO
      ACT.linkWrap = <li class="active">|</li>
      USERDEF1 < .NO
      USERDEF2 < .ACT
    }
  }  
}

config.linkVars = L
config.locale_all = de_DE
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.sys_language_overlay = 1
config.metaCharset = iso-8859-1
config.locale_all = en_GB.ISO88591
config.language = en
[GLOBAL]

[globalVar = GP:L = 7]
config.sys_language_uid = 7
config.metaCharset = iso-8859-1
config.locale_all = fr_FR.ISO88591
config.language = fr
[GLOBAL]
```

And here’s the script where I load the content to my lib-field:

```
lib.contentmid = HMENU
lib.contentmid {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1

    NO = 1
    NO {
     ATagParams = class="notUsableLink"
      wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1


      wrapItemAndSub = <section id="{field:subtitle}">|</section>
      allWrap = <div class="mainContent"><div class="contentHolder">|</div></div>

      before = <div class="hideLink" data-link="{field:subtitle}">{field:title}</div>
      before.insertData = 1

      after.cObject = CONTENT
      after.cObject {
        table = tt_content
        select {
          orderBy = sorting
          pidInList.field = uid
          languageField=sys_language_uid
          where = colPos = 2
        }

      }
    }
  }
  2 < .5
  2 {
    wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <div id="{field:subtitle}" class="subContent"><div class="contentHolder">|</div></div>
    NO.allWrap >
  }
}
```

Any idea? Many thanks.

Comment: Try to add `includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1`to `after.cObject.select`. 
The `styles.content.get` is some kind of shortcut for colPos 0 ... 3, but does not affect your TypoScript at this point

If I'm right, I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add 'includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1' to 'after.cObject.select.' The styles.content.get is some kind of shortcut for colPos 0 ... 3, but does not affect your TypoScript at this point.

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 version 11 the problem might occur at least for extbase extensions too.
This case can be solved with the extension https://github.com/georgringer/extbase_with_no_l10n_parent.